# Jaxb XML namespaces incorrect when using generics and base classes

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I have four classes in two namespaces, two in one package are used as base classes to the two in the other, for example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo<T extends Bar> {

    @XmlElement(name="Bar")
    private List<T> bar;

}
```

And

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bar {
    // something
}
```

The derived classes look like:

```
@XmlType(name="Foo" namespace="urn:foo/Bar")
@XmlRootElement(name="Foo")
public class DerivedFoo extends Foo<DerivedBar> {
    // something
}
```

And

```
@XmlType(name="Bar" namespace="urn:foo/Bar")
public class DerivedBar extends Bar {
    // something
}
```

In the package which contains the base classes, there is no `package-info.java` or anything containing namespace information.  The package containing the derived classes has all of the namespace information.

The output XML is properly (sort of) namespacing the `DerivedFoo` class but is assigning the `DerivedBar` class to an unnamed namespace, essentially:

```
<Response xmlns:ns2="urn:foo/Bar">
  <ns2:Foo>
    <Bar>
    </Bar>
  </ns2:Foo>
</Response>
```

Comment: Can you share the steps to reproduce the issue (maybe a command line call or maven plugin config)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a combination of [`@XmlElementRef`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html) and [`@XmlRootElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html). Using the `@XmlElementRef` annotation is like saying "here's a thing; go look at its `@XmlRootElement` annotation to figure out how to serialize it."

The following setup seems to do what you're looking for. Base classes:

```
package base;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo<T extends Bar> {

    @XmlElementRef
    public List<T> bar;

}
```

```
package base;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bar {
    // something
}
```

```
package base;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Request {

    @XmlElementRef
    public Foo<?> foo;
}
```

And subclasses:

```
package derived;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Foo", namespace = "urn:foo/Bar")
public class DerivedFoo extends Foo<DerivedBar> {
    // something
}
```

```
package derived;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Bar", namespace = "urn:foo/Bar")
public class DerivedBar extends Bar {
    // something
}
```

---

Looks pretty good from my test:

```
@Test
public void tryIt() throws Exception {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Request.class, DerivedFoo.class, DerivedBar.class);

    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    Request request = new Request();
    DerivedFoo foo = new DerivedFoo();
    request.foo = foo;
    foo.bar = new ArrayList<DerivedBar>();
    foo.bar.add(new DerivedBar());

    marshaller.marshal(request, System.out);
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Request xmlns:ns2="urn:foo/Bar">
    <ns2:Foo>
        <ns2:Bar/>
    </ns2:Foo>
</Request>
```

---

### Bonus

Since `@XmlElementRef` looks up the XML bindings dynamically at runtime, it will "just work" if you declare another subclass of `Bar` with a different namespace. ***Be careful*** though, because the element name is also dynamic, which might lead to weird results if your derived classes don't all use the same `name` attribute:

```
<Request xmlns:ns2="urn:rock/roll" xmlns:ns3="urn:yummy">
    <ns2:FooFighters>
        <ns3:TikiBar/>
    </ns2:FooFighters>
</Request>
```

The nested types probably don't care too much, but I bet whoever is consuming `Request` would probably not recognize those element names.